# Reading a config from a file

Tags: c, string, io, fopen

So i am trying to read from a text file and put it in a variable

in the text file there is

```
NAME= Bame
GAME= Fame
```

I've heard of strsep/strtok but i'm still having issues and with this code i get Segmentation Fault 11

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
char *token;
char *string;
char *tofree;
FILE *fp;
const char *file = "/tmp/test.txt"; 
fp = fopen(file, "r");
while(!feof(fp)) {
fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp);
token = strsep(&string, ",");
printf("%s", string);
}
fclose(fp);
exit(0);    
}
```

Comment: `char* string;` is _not_ a string. It is a pointer to a `char` that points "nowhere" since it is not initialized. You write into this uninitialized pointer thus invoking UB. Hence the crash. Fix by using character arrays: `char string[100];`. Also see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). So, replace your `feof` with  your `fgets`.

Comment: `fp = fopen(file, "r"); if (fp == NULL) { perror(Error opening file: "); return 1;}`

Comment: See also [Why is while( !feof(file) ) always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is from this line:

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp);
```

The second parameter should be ['Maximum number of characters to be copied into str'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). You should have initialised `string` to something before calling this function. If you look at the example in the link I gave, changing `string` to a character array will help you more forward.

```
char string[100];
....
fgets(string, 100, fp);
```

Previously you were passing `sizeof(string)`, however since string was actually a pointer type, you were passing the size of a pointer in bytes (either 4 or 8 depending on platform). `string` was also an unallocated pointer, so fgets would have been potentially writing to a random memory address.